# SSIS Package runs fine in VS2019 but it fails immediately when it is deployed in SSISDB on SQL 2019

Tags: sql, ssis

SSIS Package runs fine in VS2019 but it fails immediately when it is deployed in SSISDB on SQL 2019. This is the error I get , I am not sure where problem lies , pls. help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's missing the connection managers on the deployed project.

Go to the SSIS Project on the server you deployed to, right click and click configure, click tab 'Connection Managers' and see that you have the correct details in there.

Answer (score 0):

Could be related to 32/64 bit incompatibility, worth checking that the package has been built in 64 and in SSISDB is set to run in 64, or both are 32.
To check the built, in visual studio go to project->properties->debugging and note  the value of Run64BitRuntime:

[image]

In SQL Server go to Integration Services navigate to the package and right click on it; note the checkbox 32 bit runtime.

[image]

make sure both are in line.

Also, if the package is running through SQL Agent you may need to check how it is running. Go to the job step properties, click Edit and note the checkbox 32 bit runtime at the bottom.